# VS 2017 + UWP - create app package fails - language file not found

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, windows-10-mobile

I am using Visual Studio 2017 community edition to develop a Windows universal app:

Target version: Windows 10 creators update (10.0;Build 15063)

Min version: Windows 10 November update (10.0;Build 10586)

(I am mostly deploying it on my Windows 10 mobile phone and it works in ARM + DEBUG fine, but completely doesn't work in Release mode...).

I finished with the development and I want to upload the app to the store. I use to do this for Windows phone 8.1 and it worked fine, but here for Win 10 when I try to create the app package (release + ARM), after like half-hour build, I get an error:

[image]

Because of this, I cannot get my appxupload file to use for store publication.

My app has 2 supported languages - en-GB and pl-PL, I tried to add in the manifest file default language both en-GB and pl-PL, but in both cases, for some reason, the other language appx file is not created into the build folder.

My resources folder looks like this:

[image]

I tested and both languages work fine on my test phone when I deploy from VS 2017 in Debug mode (release doesn't work...).

The resources file are set as PRIResource like this:

[image]

I used the windows app certification kit on the .appx files I got in the build folder and all was okay.

A completely separate problem (but perhaps related) is that my app works in Debug mode but it cannot be launched on my phone if I use Release mode... I'm using SQLite and some local folder reading/writing operations, but that's a problem for another post I guess...

So I ran out of ideas and I can't find any help on the Internet... Any ideas?

Thanks.

**Small update:**

when I unchecked the option "Compile with.NET native tool chain" on my Universal Windows project, I was able to deploy the app in the Release+ARM mode and everything seem to work fine (especially the SQLite operations). However the create app package still gives me that language error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> However the create app package still gives me that language error.

This error can be a [known issue](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1fd15b80-5955-4f37-9350-7576ea1679b0/uwp15063-package-can-not-have-3-language-resource?forum=wpdevelop) on Creator Update and Visual Studio 2017.

Currently there is a hot-fix here: 
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/40376/error-file-csomepathbinarmreleaseapp-112180-scale.html .

Comment: This was exactly the problem... I applied the hotfix from the link and the create app package worked... thank you so much, it was a painful experience...